# cannot find 'EXUpdatesControllerRegistry' in scope

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-build, eas

While building my app with expo for preview, I ran into this bug which I've been stuck on for a while and I'm not exactly sure why this occured.

EXPO-SDK 45

PLATFORM: IOS

WORKFLOW: BARE

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `expo-dev-client` do you use ?

Do you use `expo-build-properties` ?

Comment: I'm on expo sdk 45, and I use eas build --platform all --profile preview